# ArcGIS dashboard Arcade Using multiple If/else if statements

Tags: arcade, operations-dashboard

I try to write an Arcade expression in dashboard indicator, the expression has 4 `if` statements but only the first two statements are works the code is below:

```
############################################

var`enter code here`ar kmillion = 10000000;
var million = 1000000;
var k100 = 100000;

var name_km = Left($datapoint["sum_VALUE"],2) 
var name_m  = Left($datapoint["sum_VALUE"],1) 
var name_k100 = Left($datapoint["sum_VALUE"],3) 
var name_k99 =  Left($datapoint["sum_VALUE"],2)

if ($datapoint["sum_VALUE"] >= kmillion) {
    return {
        topText: 'اجمالي عدد التلاميذ',
        topTextColor: '#a80000',
        topTextOutlineColor: '',
        topTextMaxSize: 'small',
        middleText: name_km,
        middleTextColor: '',
        middleTextOutlineColor: '',
        middleTextMaxSize: 'large',
        bottomText: 'مليون تلميذ',
        iconName:'icon1',
        iconAlign:'left',
        iconColor:'',
        iconOutlineColor:''
        
    }
}

else if ($datapoint["sum_VALUE"] >= million < kmillion  ) {
    return{ 
        topText: 'اجمالي عدد التلاميذ',
        topTextColor: '#a80000',
        topTextOutlineColor: '',
        topTextMaxSize: 'small',
        middleText: name_m,
        middleTextColor: '',
        middleTextOutlineColor: '',
        middleTextMaxSize: 'large',
        bottomText: '2مليون تلميذ',
        iconName:'icon1',
        iconAlign:'left',
        iconColor:'',
        iconOutlineColor:''
        
    }
}

else {
    return {
        topText: 'اجمالي عدد التلاميذ',
        topTextColor: '#a80000',
        topTextOutlineColor: '',
        topTextMaxSize: 'small',
        middleText: name_k100,
        middleTextColor: '',
        middleTextOutlineColor: '',
        middleTextMaxSize: 'large',
        bottomText: 'ألف تلميذ',
        iconName:'icon1',
        iconAlign:'left',
        iconColor:'',
        iconOutlineColor:''
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never hit the final "else" condition. You should use this conditional instead for the second "else if"

```
else if ($datapoint["sum_VALUE"] >= million  ) {
```

The code already checked if the value is greater or equal to kmillion in the first if statement.

If you need to check whether a value is between two numbers in an if statement, you have to use something like

```
if (value >= 10 and value < 20)
```